# Fill view model after fill another properties

Tags: c#

I have a Model like:

```
 public class PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
        public string Item3 { get; set; }
        public string Item4 { get; set; }
        public IList<PreliminaryPurchaseOrderDesignNameViewModel> PreliminaryDesignNames { get; set; } = new List<PreliminaryPurchaseOrderDesignNameViewModel>();

        public class PreliminaryPurchaseOrderDesignNameViewModel
        {
            public List<IEnumerable> DesignName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

So I fill item objects as:

```
List<PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel> result = new List<PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel>();
 try
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(".csv"))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(model.PreliminaryFile.File))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(memory))

                        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                        {
                            var record = new PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel();
                            var records = csv.EnumerateRecords(record);

                            foreach (var r in records)
                            {
                                PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel tempResult = new PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel
                                {
                                    Item1 = r.Item1,
                                    Item2 = r.Item2,
                                    Item3 = r.Item3,
                                    Item4 = r.Item4,
                                };
                                result.Add(tempResult);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

So I get list of ViewModel into another method that I execute as:

```
var designNames = _purchaseOrderRepository.GetPreliminaryDesignNames(fileName);
```

My question is: how can I fill that model:  `PreliminaryDesignNames { get; set; }` once another records are added into `foreach`, something like:

```
result.Add(designNames);
```

But specifying to fill that view model. How can I do that? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**. operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operator) to access *PreliminaryDesignNames* property from instance of *PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel* type (tempResult in your code)

```
...
foreach (var r in records)
{
    PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel tempResult = new PurchaseOrderPreliminaryCSVModel
    {
        Item1 = r.Item1,
        Item2 = r.Item2,
        Item3 = r.Item3,
        Item4 = r.Item4,
    };
    var designNames = _purchaseOrderRepository.GetPreliminaryDesignNames(fileName);
    tempResult.PreliminaryDesignNames.AddRange(designNames);
    result.Add(tempResult);
}
...
```

Comment: I'd upvote but this is a code-only answer, which are discouraged.